# Issue with launching Android application via Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

My problem is thus; I am new to programming on the ANDROID platform and have a 'working' application that piggy-backs on the API-Docs example. I wish it to launch three tabs one containing a list of reports, one a form to file a report and the last to show the geo-located reports. It doesn't appear as a separate application, it instead appears as a list to be launched by the API-Docs example. Below is my manifest code...

```
    <activity android:name=".HelloFlamingos">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Controls2" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".List1" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ReviewTab" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

HelloFlamingos is the initial page that I wish to be displayed, I realise that the intents for this are wrong, have thought about using category: VIEWS, action: DEFAULT, however is seemingly unwilling to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what context is the activity started? If you're looking to have the `HelloFlamingos` activity the first displayed from the Android OS, you should change its category in the manifest to `category.LAUNCHER`.

If you're looking to start the activity from elsewhere in your app, create an Intent which matches what you've specified (`category.SAMPLE_CODE`) and use `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`.